# How do I pass a variable from one model to another in Yii?

Tags: php, yii

I have this code which is inside a view Inventory.php from a model named Inventory. This is used to display the current ID being viewed:

```
<?php $inventoryID = $model->inventory_id; ?> <--- this one.

<h3>View Info for Inventory No. <?php echo $inventoryID; ?>: <?php echo $model->brand->brand; ?> <?php echo $model->model;?></h3>
```

I want to use it in another model named InventoryHistory because it will be saved in the InventoryHistory database. How do I do that?

Answer (score 1):

You are not approaching this correctly. You should not think in terms of "how do I use this same ID in another model" after you have already created the database schema and models and you've even created the views! You should define these relationships on the database level and then map them to models with the correct relations between them. Then, you will have everything you need available to you and you will know how to get this ID in the other model. Here's a useful link to get you started - http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/database.arr

Answer (score 0):

Assuming inventoryID is the PK of InventoryHistory,

```
$inventoryID = $model->inventory_id;
$history = InventoryHistory::model()->findByPk($inventoryID);
```

Comment: sorry i'm not clear with my question. I'll revise it in a bit. but thank you for your answer. it gave me an idea :)

Answer (score 0):

Samuel's approach is correct, but if you want carry any type of variable inside whole app, you can use global varables with setState and getState, you also check varable with hasState. 
In Yii 1.
Yii::app()->user->setState('key','value');
Yii::app()->user->getState('key');
To unset:
Yii::app()->user->setState('key',null);